# How add an object into the array list that is value of another object in Redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a initial state that has vocabulary object with key number and each key has array of object, In the React redux we use spread and update our state in the reducer , but in redux toolkit , I stucked , I want to add a object to array of each key

```
const initialState: IWordListState = {
  vocabulary: {
    7:[
      {}
    ]
  },
};
```

```
export const wordSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'words',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addWord: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ step: number; newWord: WordState }>,
    ) => {
      console.log(current(state));
      const { step, newWord } = action.payload;
      state.vocabulary[step] = [{ ...newWord }];
    },
  },
});
```

I want to add another object in calling addWord function , I get a step number as key of vocabulary object like this :

```
  vocabulary: {
    7:[
         {
        id:211,
        ....
       },
       {
        id:212,
        ....
       }
    ],
    6:[
      {
        id:213,
        ....

     ]

  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update like this:

```
state.vocabulary[step] = state.vocabulary[step] ? [...state.vocabulary[step], newWord] : [newWord]
```

Comment: Hey @viet , thanks , I test it , but i got this error `TypeError: state.vocabulary[step] is not iterable`

Comment: Because `state.vocabulary[step]` is not an array. please check your data again

Comment: I updated this answer with check condition before using spread operator

Answer (score 0):

Check if this one works:

```
addWord: (
  state,
  action: PayloadAction<{ step: number; newWord: WordState }>,
) => {
  console.log(current(state));
  const { step, newWord } = action.payload;
  state.vocabulary[step].push(newWord);
},
```

Comment: Thank you erfan , It works if i set for each key a empty array , and if i have a lot of keys in each rendering I store them ,
`vocabulary: {
    7: [],
    6: [],
    5: [],
  },
`